# How Can I Obtain the ObjectID of a NSManagedObject Retrieved via a Relationship?

Tags: performance, core-data, predicate, nsmanagedobject

I have a resultset from a keyword query.  Each keyword object returned has a many-to-many relationship to another entity. ( call it B )

What I'm wondering is there a way to use the keyword `resultset` and find only the managed objectIDs to the `B` entities without having to pull them into memory?  Currently, I've been doing this:

```
NSMutableArray *objIdList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSArray *keywordResultSet = <results from initial keyword query>;
for ( Keyword *keyword in keywordResultSet )
{
    B *mo = [keyword valueForKey: <relationship>];
    [objIdlist addObject: [mo objectID]];
}
// additional sorting of result set
```

The problem is the it is SUPER slow when I do this.  Is there a way to only get the ObjectIDs?

Comment: I should add that what I was asking here was for the objectid of the object on the other side of the relationship not "keyword"  There doesn't seem to be a way to do that.  granted I could probably use some other field of the referenced entity, but I'm asking on a generic level.  I don't want to have to know that a specific property exists. Using objectIds are supposed to allow me to do this, since they are unique to each object and safe to use across threads and contexts.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to ask is if you need objectIDs at all. A lot of Core Data novices believe that objectIDs are like keys in a relational database. They aren't. You only need objectIDs when you have a need to refer to objects in another persistent store. Otherwise, they don't do you much good. I think it highly unlikely, given your relative inexperience with Core Data, that you actually need to obtain objectIDs in the first place.

For any other attribute other than objectIDs, you could do a fetch by attribute and set the result type to dictionary which produces a lightweight fetch that returns only an array of dictionaries containing the value of the one attribute sought. You can't do that with objectIDs because the objectIDs are not strictly speaking attributes of the managed objects but rather references to them in a particular persistent store.

Comment: my understanding of the managedobjectids are that they are persistent across stores and contexts and are very lightweight as they are just that references.  Anytime I need to use a property from the referenced object, it is faulted in.  but I don't need any property right away I shouldn't need to fault the entire mo.  Using the objectid is the right way is what I've interpreted.  The apple docs recommend to use them so I'm not sure we understand each other in this.